# Arcpy InsertCursor inserting geometry into Shape field

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, cursor

I'm trying to write a script that reads geometry for each row in feature class, then create a new feature class and insert into it that geometry. It has to work with ArcGIS 10.0 so I have to use `arcpy.InsertCursor`. But I have a problem, because in the new feature class there is the same number of rows as in input but every row has the same geometry, from last row of previous feature. In 10.2, even using `arcpy.InsertCursor`, everything is working fine.

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace
infile=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
outfc="przekroje_oblicz_hydroo.shp"
outpath="C:\\Users\\Bartek\\Desktop\\temp"
shapeName = arcpy.Describe(infile).shapeFieldName

linie=[]
km=[]
ID_HYDRO_R="12334"
#ver=arcpy.GetInstallInfo()['Version']
ver="10.0"

if ver=="10.0":
    cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(infile)
    for row in cursor:
        linie.append(row.getValue(shapeName))
        km.append(row.getValue("Km"))    

else:
    for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(infile, ["SHAPE@","Km"]):
        linie.append(row[0])
        km.append(row[1])


PUWG92 = "PROJCS['PUWG_1992',GEOGCS['GCS_ETRS_1989',DATUM['D_ETRS_1989',SPHEROID['GRS_1980',6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION['Transverse_Mercator'],PARAMETER['false_easting',500000.0],PARAMETER['false_northing',-5300000.0],PARAMETER['central_meridian',19.0],PARAMETER['scale_factor',0.9993],PARAMETER['latitude_of_origin',0.0],UNIT['Meter',1.0]]"
fc=arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(outpath, outfc, "POLYLINE", "", "", "ENABLED", PUWG92)
#fc=arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(outpath, outfc, "POINT", "", "", "ENABLED", PUWG92)
arcpy.AddField_management(fc, "ID_HYDRO_R", "STRING", "", "", "22", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")
arcpy.AddField_management(fc, "KM_PKT", "DOUBLE", "6", "3", "", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")
arcpy.AddField_management(fc, "ZW_10", "DOUBLE", "7", "2", "", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")
arcpy.AddField_management(fc, "ZW_1", "DOUBLE", "7", "2", "", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")
arcpy.AddField_management(fc, "ZW_02", "DOUBLE", "7", "2", "", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")
arcpy.AddField_management(fc, "ZW_WZ", "DOUBLE", "7", "2", "", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")

if ver=="10.0":
    k=0
    cur = arcpy.InsertCursor(fc)
    for i in linie:
        feat = cur.newRow()
        feat.Shape = i
        feat.ID_HYDRO_R=ID_HYDRO_R
        feat.KM_PKT=((float(km[k])/1000))
        feat.ZW_10=11
        feat.ZW_1=12
        feat.ZW_02=12
        feat.ZW_WZ=-7777
        cur.insertRow(feat)
        k+=1

else:
    cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(fc, ["SHAPE@","KM_PKT"])
    k=0
    for i in linie:
        kma=(float(km[k])/1000)
        #arcpy.AddMessage
        cursor.insertRow([i,kma])
        k+=1


del cursor, cur
```

EDIT:

I managed to rewrtie geometry by modyfying searchcursor to read vertex into 'arcpy.Array', then create 'arcpy.Polyline' and add it to list linie. But it is much slower solution.

```
cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(infile)
for row in cursor:
    feat=row.getValue(shapeName)
    k=0
    punkty_lista=arcpy.Array()
    for part in feat:
        for pnt in feat.getPart(k):
            punkty_lista.add(pnt)
    linia=arcpy.Polyline(punkty_lista)
    linie.append(linia)
    punkty_lista.removeAll()
    k=+1
```

Comment: ArcGIS 10.0 has been in Retired support status for nearly three years, so this isn't really even an issue for Esri Tech Support. Are you sure there isn't an ancient Python aspect to this issue as well?

Comment: May not be the source of your problem but `fc` in your code is actually a RESULT object. So if you called it `res` then typically you get the FeatureClass path as `fc = res.getOutput(0)`.

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint at `for i in linie` to see if `i` is actually changing on each iteration? Or you could put a breakpoint even a bit before that to see what your `linie` list contains after your `for row in cursor` line. Not sure it works for 10.0 but you could try changing that one to `row[0]` also to see if that works instead of `getValue()`

Comment: @Hornbydd: Nothing has changed. When i print the object list it looks like they are all different.